# How to use vector <struct> of other class

Tags: c++, nana

```
//TreeBox.h
#pragma once
#include "ListBox.h"
struct ItemInfo
{
    std::string _fileName;
    std::string _childName;
    std::string _time;
    std::string _format;
    std::string _size;

    std::string _nodeKey;
};
class TreeBox
{
 ...
}
```

```
//ListBox.h
class
{
 public:
 std::vector<ItemInfo> _itemList; //compile error
 
}
```

I wanna use std::vector in "ListBox.h" from using struct in "TreeBox.h"
but it was compile error allocator C2903

how do I use that?

Comment: please add the error you are getting , are you including TreeBox.h to ListBox.h ?

Comment: It isn't idiomatic C++ to use `_underscore` names for public fields.

Comment: What is `_size` meant to represent? why not use a numeric type instead of a string?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and include the _exact_ error message produced by your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need not to include ListBox.h in TreeBox.h
2. Always follow practice of including standard libraries first and then the .h  files

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class ListBox;
struct ItemInfo
{
    std::string _fileName;
    std::string _childName;
    std::string _time;
    std::string _format;
    std::string _size;

    std::string _nodeKey;
};
class TreeBox
{

};
```

```
#pragma once
#include <initializer_list>
#include "TreeBox.h"

class ListBox
{
public:

    std::vector <ItemInfo> _itemList;
private:

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `#include <vector>` to the top of your header to include the STL vector. #including a file header at the top of a file allows you to access the objects defined in that header.

Comment: thanks i already include <vector> but it was mistake Question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're including `ListBox.h` at the beginning of `TreeBox.h`. Specifically, you're including it *before* the part of `TreeBox.h` that defines `ItemInfo`.

So, you're trying to define a `vector<ItemInfo>` before the compiler knows what an `ItemInfo` might be, and it doesn't like that.

Rearrange your definitions so by the time the compiler sees the code trying to create a `vector<ItemInfo>`, it has already seen the definition of `ItemInfo` (and be sure you've included `<vector>`, in case you don't have that yet).

So with things in the correct order, you'd have something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector> // First, tell the compiler about `vector`

class ItemInfo {  // ...and `ItemInfo`
    // ...
};

class ListBox {
    std::vector<ItemInfo> itemList;  // *Then* we can use `vector` and `ItemInfo`
    // ...
};
```

If you want some of the pieces of that to be in separate headers that you `#include`, that's fine--but you still need to get the definitions in the right order.

Comment: oh thanks i understood your means (compiler don't know "between ListBox.h and TreeBox.h" defined struct ItemInfo

How do I tell the compiler the order of definitions?

Comment: @Lucius__: The compiler reads through files in order, so you just have to assure that the definition of `ItemInfo` comes before the code that tries to use it.

Comment: @Lucius__ Just put things from lowest-level to highest level. Since `ListBox` uses stuff from `TreeBox` (specifically `ItemInfo`), then `ListBox logically comes after `TreeBox`. How can `TreeBox` reference something that logically comes after it? (This gets complicated when things don't order logically, but in this case, simply ordering them logically solves the problem.)